# Amazon EC2 SSH Failed to connect "Bad File Number"

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

This is the command I am told to use by clicking connect in the control panel

```
ssh -i private_key.pem root@instancePublicDNS
```

Well, that one failed so I wanted to know what happen so I ran:

```
ssh -vvv private_key.pem root@instancePublicDNS
```

> OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
> debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
> debug1: Connecting to private_key.pem [***.***.***.***] port 22.
> debug1: connect to address ***.***.***.*** port 22: Attempt to connect timed out without establishing a connection.
> ssh: connect to host private_key.pem port 22: Bad file number

Any Ideas?
I have searched for the answer on Google and serverfault, I found a few possible solutions that did not work.

info about the instance

AMI-ID : ami-688c7801 ( ubuntu 10.10 Server )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure "Security Groups" to allow ssh:

- open https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/
- NETWORKING & SECURITY->Security Groups
- select default
- add rules to SSH(for your ip or 0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: @Mark if the answer is correct, then confirmed it

Comment: I think most people forget to apply rules changes. I did.

Comment: Does not work. I already have this in the rules. But after an instance reboot, ssh-ing does not work.